# Event Passthrough Canvas

Tags: javascript, events, gwt, canvas, overlay

I have a canvas that I am overlaying on top of a google map widget (using a gwt gmaps wrapper). All the mouse events such as double click and drag are of course hitting the canvas first and would need to sink them to the maps api underneath.

The question is, is there a way I could sink specific mouse events directly to the map widget without having to write an event handler that calls the api specific actions. basically something that would make the canvas act like it wasn't there. I know, I am probably end up implementing all the events but thought this question is worth exploring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, something along these lines should do the trick for you:

```
// Your custom event handler function for the canvas.
function event_handler(e) {
  // Do stuff.

  // Pass the event to your gmaps parent container.
  $("#gwt_gmaps_parent_container").trigger(e);
}

// Bind your custom event handler to the canvas.
$("#canvas").bind("click", event_handler);
```

Depending on your event propagation setup and how Google Maps deals with layering (I've never worked with it before), you may need to trigger the event on the widget itself.

**Edit:** This approach won't handle more complex interactions like dragging and dropping or scroll wheel zooming. Unfortunately, you'll probably have to write a custom handler for those events to directly make API calls.

If you only need a subset of the mouse events to affect your overlaid canvas, you might want to instead pass the events captured by the widget to your canvas.